# VSCode Remote Server stuck on initializing server

Tags: visual-studio-code, remote-server

I'm currently trying to access a remote server using VS Code's Remote SSH extension. I haven't had a problem when using it before (that was around a month ago) but today when I tried to access the server I ran into some trouble.

I have the hostname and everything configured in a `config` file, and so I just click on that option and type in the password. However, VS Code seems to be stuck on "Opening Remote..." for the past hour or so. The dialogue I get in the terminal is as follows:

```
username@host's password:
Running remote connection script
Acquiring lock on /home/username/.vscode-server/bin/abcdefghijklmnop1234567989/
    vscode-remote-lock.abcdefghijklmnop1234567989
Installing to /home/username/.vscode-server/bin/abcdefghijklmnop1234567989...
Downloading with wget
```

Does anybody know what the problem might be? Is this normal?

**EDIT**

As soon as I posted this the connection was successfully made. However, I would also like to still know what the problem was and if it normally takes around an hour, and what this process might be doing. I also believe it would be helpful to the community overall.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you ever get a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't... I just remember that it started working again as mysteriously as when it stopped.

Comment: Actually, for me, it was just taking a loooong time. So, patience was a virtue. Thanks for updating

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue just now and realized that firewall protection has something to do with it.
As soon as I disabled it, the remote connection was established and I managed to see my code again.